# How to make AESEncrypt and AESDecrypt Function work in different schema of vertica properly?

Tags: encryption, vertica

I am using:

AESEncrypt(input,passphrase) - Returns an encrypted binary string

AESDecrypt(input,passphrase) - Returns the decrypted string

Source of the function: https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/encryption_package

Function in vertica to encrypt columns, But now i am facing a problem that for eg, i am having 2 schema in vertica Database as **Test1** and **Test2** and both have same table named as **testTable**. I have entered some rows in **Test1.testTable** with 1 column with encrypted values using **AESEncrypt(input,passphrase)** function. When i apply **AESDecrypt(input,passphrase)** on encrypted data column of **Test1.testTable** it successfully **decrypt** the data.

Now i have copied the Encrypted data as it is from **Test1.testTable** to **Test2.testTable**, but now when i apply **AESDecrypt(input,passphrase)** on encrypted data column of **Test2.testTable** it could not **decrypt** the data.

I need to make it possible that, i encrypt data in 1st schema and copy that encrypted data to 2nd schema and decrypt that data in 2nd Schema. This is required because ETL process needs to be done on 2nd schema.

Any kind of help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.